# Table INSERT using While loop

Tags: sql-server-2008, loops, while-loop, insert

While I've read many answers here, this is my first question on stackoverflow and I'm reasonably new to SQL.  I am trying to use a WHILE loop (SQL Server 2008) to insert some records into a table.  Here's the data I'm starting with:

```
SeasID   FacilityID   PL   Zone   Section   Row   FromSeat   ToSeat
11       17           1    g2     cf        a     1          5
32       18           14   w13    r2        c     10         12
```

I need to insert a row for every unique seat into a new table.  Here's what I'd like to insert:

```
SeasID   FacilityID   PL   Zone   Section   Row   Seat
11       17           1    g2     cf        a     1
11       17           1    g2     cf        a     2
11       17           1    g2     cf        a     3
11       17           1    g2     cf        a     4
11       17           1    g2     cf        a     5

32       18           14   w13    r2        c     10
32       18           14   w13    r2        c     11
32       18           14   w13    r2        c     12
```

I've tried many things and I don't think I understand loops very well yet. Any help you can provide would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty (Change 1000 to the highest seat number possible. A Persistent Numbers table would help)

```
;WITH N(Number) AS (SELECT 1 AS Number UNION ALL SELECT Number + 1 FROM N WHERE Number < 1000) 
SELECT TheTable.*, N.Number AS Seat
FROM TheTable  
INNER JOIN N
ON ToSeat >= N.Number AND FromSeat <= N.Number
ORDER BY N.Number
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works perfectly.  However, I'm not entirely sure how it works, but i'll take it.

Comment: The first line makes a table called N with a column called Number that has values counting up from 1 to 1000, this is used to JOIN to the data table so you can effectively duplicate rows for each N.Number where it lies between the from/to columns

Comment: I've read that I should avoid loops whenever possible.  Somehow, the loop I had was giving me 16 records, rather than 8.  At any rate, thank you for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: A recursive cte for counting is really not much better than a loop for performance. You would be far better off using a hard coded 10 rows and a cross join. Probably not a huge deal for 10k rows but if it got much bigger it would become a noticeable difference.